# closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^n {2n\choose 2k}2^k$

Tags: closed-form, combinatorial-proofs

Is it possible to  find a closed form for the expression below?
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {2n\choose 2k}2^k$$

I have tried *counting in two ways* but made no progress.

And I don't know any combinatorial identities that help me simplify the sigma.

Comment: You claim that you have tried "counting in two ways". You should probably provide your work so that people know what you have tried and can improve your answer, or save time by avoiding what you have already done.

Comment: @probablyme Imagine $2n$ persons. We are going to choose and even number ($2k$)of them. Then buy $k$ chocolates and eat some of the chocolates! I counted the number of ways we can do this (in two ways) but I got the same answer (the sigma in the question)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$\dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{j=0}^{2n} {2n \choose j} 2^{j/2} + \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{j=0}^{2n} {2n \choose j} (-2)^{j/2}$$

Comment: Indeed, good job

Answer (score 2):

$$A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}2^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\sqrt{2}^{2k} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{j}\sqrt{2}^j\left(1^j+(-1)^j\right) $$
hence $A_n$ is related with [Pell-Lucas numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number):

> $$ A_n = \frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{2n}}{2}.$$

To prove the same, you may also check that $A_{n+2}=6\,A_{n+1}-A_n$ and  $A_0=1, A_1=3$.

A combinatorial interpretation is the following: you have $2n$ officials and you want to first promote to a higher ranking an even number of them, then promote again at most half of the previously promoted officials.

Comment: Where does the third equality come from?

Comment: @Bmudtneduts: from the fact that $\frac{(-1)^j+1^j}{2}$ is zero if $j$ is odd and $1$ otherwise. By applying the binomial theorem, we easily get the closed form of $A_n$.

Comment: You want $\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n} + (1-\sqrt{2})^{2n}}{2}$, I think.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: you are clearly right. Thanks, now fixed.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Can you explain How you wrote the recurrence relation?

Comment: @MasOud: if a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ fulfills $a_n=A\cdot  \alpha^n + B\cdot \beta^n$ then $a_{n+2}=(\alpha+\beta)a_{n+1}-(\alpha\beta)a_{n}$. In this case we have $\alpha=(1+\sqrt{2})^2$ and $\beta=(1-\sqrt{2})^2$.